# Improving the running time of finding the count of pairs satisfying a symmetric relation

Tags: java, performance

I had a online coding test yesterday. The question is not hard to solve, but I could not achieve the required running time. The question is as follow:

Given 1 <= M, N <= 10^5 find the count of pairs A, B:

1. 1 <= A <= M and 1 <= B <= N
2. (A^1/3 + B^1/3)^3 is an integer

Here was my solution:

I notice that this relationship is symmetric, so if assuming M >= N, and imagining we are searching valid points on a M*N matrix, I only need to search the following three parts of the matrix:

1. Items above the diagonal: (i, j) where 1 <= i < j <= N. Increase the counter by 2 if a valid pair has found. (Symmetric relation)
2. Diagonal elements.
3. Items int (i, j) where N+1 <= i <= M, and 1<= j <= N

My java solution is as the following

```
static int cubeNumbers(int M, int N) {
    int count = 0;
    if (N > M) {
        int temp = N;
        N = M;
        M = temp;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i ++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= N; j ++) {
            if (isValid(i, j)) {count += 2;}
        }
        if (isValid(i, i)) {count += 1;}
    }
    for (int i = N + 1; i <= M; i ++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= N; j ++) {
            if (isValid(i, j)) {count += 1;}
        }
    }
    return count;
}

private static boolean isValid(int A, int B) {
    double result = Math.pow(Math.pow(A, 1.0/3) + Math.pow(B, 1.0/3), 3);
    return (result % 1) == 0;
}
```

Comment: If your code is 100% functional but you're looking for people to improve it, you should check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: I assume you're meant to restrict a and b to cube numbers, rather than working out cube roots of any old integers.

Comment: @PaulBoddington If you did, you wouldn't find results like `A=2,B=54` where result of equation is `128` (`(2^(1/3) + 54^(1/3)) ^ 3 = (1.2599210498948731647672106072782 + 3.7797631496846194943016318218347) ^ 3 = 5.0396841995794926590688424291129 ^ 3 = 128`).

Comment: @Andreas Good point, I should have thought harder before commenting. I guess you want to restrict a and b to be of the form sk^3, tk^3 (or something like that).

Comment: @Andreas Actually I think I mean ks^3, kt^3.